# Unable to use Replace function on column of custom type

Tags: postgresql, replace, casting

In order to enforce some constraints, our devs use a custom type for a type/factor column.

Custom type defined as such and includes both the old and new value:

```
create type custom_type as enum ('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'OldValue', 'NewValue');
```

I'm trying to update some values in a table like so:

```
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, 'OldValue'::custom_type, 'NewValue'::custom_type);
```

However am receiving the following error:

```
[2019-04-11 16:37:42] [42883] ERROR: function replace(column, custom_type, custom_type) does not exist
[2019-04-11 16:37:42] Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm guessing that this is going to require defining a custom "replace" function in order to handle the types or is there a way that I can handle this by just casting.

For reference this is PostgreSQL 11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace()` works on strings, not on enums. You can do what you appently want with an `UPDATE` with a `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE table
       SET column = 'NewValue'::custom_type
       WHERE column = 'OldValue'::custom_type;
```